# Safe yet strong exothermic reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, energy

I'm studying chemical engineering at uni (Belgium), and this year (my 2nd) we have to develop and build a stirling engine. It has to be powered by a relatively safe exothermic reaction (not dangerous for bystanders, so no formation of toxic fumes,...) and the whole thing is electrically controlled but that's not important here,

I've come up with this so far:

- Sodium acetate crystallization
- Hydratation of anhydrous copper sulphate
- calcium chloride and water
- sodiumhypochlorite oxidizing sodiumsulfite

An 'open flame' reaction is not allowed sadly enough..
I'm hoping to at least reach 70-80 degrees Celsius (158-176° Fahrenheit)

Chances are quite big that there are better reactions but I really can't think of anything else..

Thanks A LOT in advance everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some more options:

- Pd-catalyzed oxidation of dilute hydrogen gas in air: $\ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O}$  If you use a **dilute** hydrogen gas mix (say 95% nitrogen and 5% hydrogen), no flaming combustion can occur in air.  But oxidation still happens, at least when catalyzed by palladium particles. This is how microbiological anaerobic chambers maintain a zero-oxygen environment.  You can probably buy some catalyst fairly cheaply from a microbiology anaerobic chamber company like Coy labs.
- Phosphorus pentoxide hydration.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_pentoxide#Applications) says this reaction, $\ce{P4O10 + 6 H2O -> 4 H3PO4}$, has $\Delta H_{reac}=-177\text{ kJ/mol}$.  There is no flame and no fumes, but the reaction does create phosphoric acid, which is corrosive and can be dangerous.
- A modification of your sulfite / bleach idea: use sodium dithionite instead of sodium sulfite.  Sodium dithionite ($\ce{Na2S2O4}$) is air-unstable but if you can work out a way to handle without air exposure it will be more exothermic than sulfite.  Instead of dithionite itself you could use the much easier to handle [Rongalite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rongalite) and hypochlorite.  Possibly, using calcium hypochlorite suspensions in water (mostly insoluble) will allow you to use higher concentrations of hypochlorite and Rongalite without the reaction rate and temperature skyrocketing (since the rate will be controlled by $\ce{Ca(OCl)2}$ dissolution).

Comment: Your first suggestion reminded me of [hand-warmers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gFqzbnUO-Y), an interesting bit of old technology.

Comment: Nicolau Saker Neto, I think you meant the first suggestion in the original question, not in my answer.  Hand-warmers use sodium acetate crystallization.

Comment: I'd avoid working with phosphorus pentoxide when you have so many other options. It's extremely corrosive so you would have to be careful handling it, and phosphoric acid fumes are an irritant (although if you're just using a few grams probably not so much of an issue) Source: http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/docs/81-123/pdfs/0506.pdf (phosphoric acid fumes tolerated below 5 mg/m^3